# Subreport's page headers missing in main report, SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I  have a SSRS report  having 3 tables, one after the other, showing data from 3 different datasets. All in one RDL now.  But now i realized that i need 3 page headers depends up on the table  and the dataset in  each page's result.  Is there any possibility to do so?

i tried creating the there tables as three different rdl with  its own page headers. and call those reports as subreports in the main report.
the subreports shows the page headers on  its own execution but when executed the main report the page headers are missing.
Any idea here. is that a right way to get different page headers in to a single report.

your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty well-known limitation of SSRS since 2000.

More here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ba15e779-1de5-4c84-9d14-5739417c0258

and here: http://www.windows-tech.info/15/ddb42d342ca4bda8.php

One solution we are investigating is rendering each report individually as pdfs and then using a custom .net class, outside of SSRS, to programatically combine the pdfs.

Comment: Although this is a bit old, a decent fix is to put header information into the table.